# Want to change NavigationItem title

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I've embedded my first view into a NavigationController and then i set the segue as push.
I want to change in each view the title of the Navigation bar to display something and update it through my code.
i tried to call the navigation controller like this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"YourTitle";
```

but this wont work, how can I do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Navigation controller gets the title from the viewcontroller so
 this will do the job

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

   [super viewDidLoad];
   self.title = @"Some Title";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"YourTitle";
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: After you add a Navigation Item, you should use this sollution; instead, if you didn't add any navigation item, you can use simply: self.title. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
self.title = @"My Title"
```

This will change the navigation bars title as well as the title elements that refer to this view controller (eg.  tab bar etc.)

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"My Title";
```

This will change only the title for the navigation bar for current view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace title view too:

```
UIView* titleView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[self.navigationItem setTitleView: titleView];
```

Answer (score 0):

if u only change the navigation bar title then try this
on initwithnibname method

```
        self.title=@"your title";
```

but you want to give a color or font size of title then u want to take a UIlable on it

```
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0];
        label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

        label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
        label.text =@"your title";
        [label sizeToFit];
```